# Sqlite Injection with Update Subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-injection

I am trying to run the following query:

```
 query = """SELECT id, password_hash, salt FROM users
           WHERE username = '{0}' LIMIT 1""".format(username)
```

with this 'username'

```
 ' OR username IN ((SELECT 
(UPDATE users SET password_hash="hash") FROM users)) --
```

but i am getting this error:

```
OperationalError: near "UPDATE": syntax error
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

its not because of prepared statements or anything, because that query works:

```
 ' OR username IN ((SELECT username FROM users)) --
```

I am doing this legally on a website called stripe-ctf.com and for learning purposes.

Comment: Your resulting SQL is invalid. You can't just do an update inside a select statement.

Comment: Yeah, you either need to end the SQL Statement and start a new one (if SQLite allows multiple statements per call), or give it different logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run multiple statements, you would normally separate them using ';', e.g.

`SELECT id, password_hash, salt FROM users WHERE username = 'bob'; UPDATE users SET password_hash='hash' WHERE username='bob';`

However, you won't be able to inject this; the call `cursor.execute(query)` on line 88 of secretvault.py won't allow you to execute multiple statements (see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute): *execute() will only execute a single SQL statement.*)

You're on right path though... I won't give out the answer, but I encourage you to look into the SQLite [SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) documentation. Try to look into ways of "forcing" the SELECT statement to return additional values.

Best of luck!